# Improving Asp.net MVC Layers Arhitecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

I want to make a solid architecture for my MVC Project.

Currently, project has:

- **Database Objects** (linqToSql)
- **ViewModels** used for views
- **one Repository** used for

  ```
        - reading / editing / deleting database objects
        - creating ViewModels for page
        - other general functions
  ```

My initial structure is:

```
 MvcApplication  (MvcApplication.Common, MvcApplication.Domain, MvcApplication.Models)
      - containing all the views, controllers, repositories

 MvcApplication.Domain
      - containing linqToSql data file

 MvcApplication.Models (MvcApplication.Common, MvcApplication.Domain)
      - containing ViewModels

 MvcApplication.Common (MvcApplication.Domain)
      - containing helper functions, and Enums
```

Can you advice me creating a better architecture for this project?

Which layer should i remove or not?

Should ViewModels be in the Domain Layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewmodels are the purvey of the implementation of the views. I do not feel as though viewmodels should be in the domain.

I would do the same thing with data access. I separate that layer, and only have the interfaces for persistence in the domain. I can then inject my data access at runtime. YMMV there though. Depends on the likelyhood of you swapping out the DAL later. Same with services. Interfaces for the services in the domain. Separate assembly for implementations.

DAL abstraction like this becomes VERY handy during testing, So i can run my unit tests against mocks, or a different storage mechanism completely.

I don't know about you but I *hate* having my logic tests tied to some database someplace. With multiple people running tests, how can i be sure of the integrity of the test DB, unless i do sql express?

I can't even tell you the number of times abstracting the services like that have saved my bacon. What, this services is slow because its all sync? Lets change the service implementation to shove a message in a queue. No changes to the application layers or anything.